# Non-gaussian white noise examples

Tags: stochastic-processes, gaussian

What are some examples of a continuous-time non-Gaussian white noise process?

Comment: What do you mean?  White noise just refers to noise that is distributed independently of the frequency of the primary signal.  No assumption is made regarding the shape of the distribution.  Just take your favorite non-Gaussian.

Comment: To stress:  saying that noise is "Gaussian" does not imply that it is "white".  One can have noise which is gaussian at each frequency, but with parameters that vary with the frequency.  It is true that people often misuse the term.  See, e.g., [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) for a general discussion.

Comment: It seems you want to generalize [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise) to be non-Gaussian, but to stay white & probably still additive. Does that help you make a clarifying edit to your question?

Comment: Just commenting, if you take a stochastic process and calculate the correlation, white noise mean that if you compare $x(t)$ and $x(t +\tau)$ these random variables are not correlated where $E\{ x(t) x(t+\tau)\} = q \delta (\tau)$. So in an intuitive way the $x(t +\tau)$ does not depend on $x(t)$. Effectively as @lulu says you can take whatever distribution and assume it is white noise in terms of autocorrelation.

Comment: So when you calculate probability density of variables $x(t)$ by plotting a histogram, for example, it will be as distribution you choose. However, the way the variables appear over time is governed by the correlation.

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used non-Gaussian white noise process is a [Lévy flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_flight). There, the increments are independent at different times, and follow a non-Gaussian distribution, namely a [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution), which has power-law tails. This type of nosie also comes up in research problems such as [here](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.103.052115). Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of this work.

Comment: i often see Gaussian white noise defined as a process $x(t)$ with $\langle x(t) \rangle =0$ and $\langle x(t) x(s)\rangle = 2 D \delta(t-s)$ but as far as i can tell this is true for all white noise. when you derive the average dynamics for physical systems driven by white noise, these are the only two properties you employ. So what effect would the noise being non-gaussian have?

Comment: The first two moments (=the first two cumulants) completely define a process only if you **assume** that it is Gaussian, which follows from the formalism of generating functions. Lévy white noise does **not** even have a second moment at equal times, due to long power-law tails in the distribution which lead to a divergence. Gaussian noise arises from noise sources at statistical equilibrium (heat baths). Non-Gaussian noise arises from non-equilibrium noise sources. Lévy noise implies extreme events in amplitude that are absent from Gaussian noise and drastically change in behaviour.

Comment: Apologies this is all very confusing to me still. I thought all white noise has a divergence in the second moment at equal times. Sort of implied by the delta function and also by the fact that the spectral density is flat.

Comment: In fact this is getting me to the root of my problem. How can you say that continuous-time white noise is gaussian or otherwise? At each point in time x(t) is drawn from an infinite variance distribution. In what sense can that be gausssian? Does it only make sense if you see it as the derivative of a Wiener process? So when you say that Levy white noise does not have a second moment at equal times, do you mean that even with the second moment under an integral there is a divergence?

Comment: I've found some explanation in Van Kampen's Stochastic Processes in Physics and Chemistry. He mentions that Gaussian white noise should have the usual Gaussian property for higher moments  i.e. $\langle x(t_1) x(t_2) x(t_3) x(t_4) \rangle = \langle x(t_1) x(t_2) \rangle\langle x(t_3) x(t_4) \rangle +\cdots$ So when would you ever use this property? Why do physicists always need to specify that the white noise is gaussian when they dont use this property.

Comment: You're right, it is Gaussian in the sense that it is the derivative of the Wiener process, whose increments are distributed according to a Gaussian distribution. For non-Gaussian processes, these increments are not Gaussian, but follow a different distribution, such as a stable law. In the Gaussian case, the increments have a finite variance, but not in the Lévy case. The main motivation for Gaussian noise is the CLT which states that the sum of many small independent disturbances is Gaussian. This, however, requires a finite second moment of all disturbances. Else, one finds Lévy noise.

Comment: The second moment in the Gaussian noise case can be interpreted as temperature of the heat bath, in the Lévy case (out of equilibrium) this temperature diverges. Gaussian noise is so convenient because it's sufficient to specify the first two moments and say that it's Gaussian to fully define the process.